# Getting weird layout for Sencha project while running on Windows 8.1

Tags: css, windows, webkit, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have a `sencha` project is perfectly running on Android, on browser like `Google Chrome` but when I am trying to run the same project on Windows 8.1 or Internet Explorer the css styles are not rendering and the UI looks weird.

Below are the code snippets:

```
.button-grey {
    color:white !important;
    background-color:transparent !important;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#c3c3c4,#e1e1e2) !important;
}
```

The line  `-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#c3c3c4,#e1e1e2)`  is causing the problem. I am suspecting this because I am not sure whether Windows 8.1 or IE supports webkit.

Comment: Tag your question with "css", will get help sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, IE does not support the `-wekbkit` prefixed CSS properties. You'll need to find the appropriate alternative for IE. Of course, it also depends on *which* version of IE you're trying to support. <=IE8 don't support CSS3 gradients, so you may have to create a background image for that case.

Comment: @arthur- Thanks for the comment. But the css I referred here is not created by me but has been generated by Sencha. Is there a way to tell Sencha not to generate css with -webkit prefixes?

Comment: No, Sencha Touch was originally designed for Webkit browsers, and it doesn't look like the CSS will get an update anytime soon. If you make the upgrade to Ext JS 6 you'll likely be able to... but that will cost you some money.